# friendly way of displaying comments on an alternating background table

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table that is dynamically built with PHP from a sql server database that looks like this:

[image]

For every `TYPE` where I have the text **READY** or **NOT READY**, I would like to display a row underneath that looks like like this:

```
Comment: Resident is having trouble with paperwork
```

I tried to make a mock up using EXCEL, but my artistic abilities are non-existent.

[image]

I would be most grateful on suggestions on how to make this table is still alternate and look good, even though I need to add an extra row for those specific entries.

Comment: post your php-code that produced the output above!

Comment: yes please post your php-code, we cannot help you if we do not know your method of approach.  For example you could be using a third party gridview service with a very specific set of commands